# running php scripts without xampp

Tags: php, htdocs

I have my own domain and I installed wordpress manually. I currenty have a wordpress theme on the site that I haven't touched. I'm new to developing, but I installed wordpress manually without the help of any installers. I made the wp-config file from the wp-config-sample file and entered the database info like I was supposed to, but I still need to secure the passwords. And I locked down the ports I was supposed to in plesk. So I know a little so far but I have a very basic question. In xampp, you run php files in localhost after placing them in the htdocs folder. But now I have my own site. How do I run a php file now that I have my own site and server and don't need to use the apache server?

Comment: As you are working with wordpress on your main domain that have php files also. You dont need to install apache yourself there. Install some file manager plugin and upload the files in the root or other folder and access the file using your own domain. Like you create a folder in root named "phpfiles" and upload php file named "file.php" within it. Now you can access that file using domain.com/phpfiles/file.php

Comment: Wordpress depends on a web server capable of running PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to run a phpinfo file to see if mcrypt was installed. I was able to see the php info by doing what you told me to do. Now I have another question. How can I get mcrypt installed? With xammp, I added the extension to the dynamic extensions in the php configuration file, then  added the dll extension in the extensions folder in xammp. Do you know how I can add it to the php version that my hosting server has?